# How can I zoom in on Flash applications?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, flash, adobe-flash

I often use applications made in Flash. Due to my high resolution the standard browser zoom  means that everything in these applications is too small.

Using the default zoom function in all major browsers I have tested does not zoom the Flash content, so that does not help.

My best solution at the moment is to keep changing the screen resolution. This is, however, tedious, so my question is whether there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can right click on the Flash region and click "Zoom In". It only works for Flash files that has not disabled the options in the right-click menu. Also, the zoom will be limited to the Flash frame. If your browser has developer tools, you can open it and manually tweak the Flash embed's size.

Comment: This does not work for any of the apps I am using, but I will keep it in mind.

Comment: there is a way to hack flash apps and get a flash app to allow zoom, and also hack the res, using simple flash script decompilers (which is just the script) , but it still will not zoom the Frame/window itself as GMMan already indicated. hacking the flash Res, also has no real value for most of the flashes, because the parts and pieces are all set in specific locations X-Y cords and all.  About the most that could be done is using a Magnifyer :-) for the screen?? Keep the flash as it was made , and re-interpolate, which just leaves flash interaction while magnified.

Comment: @Psycogeek AFAIK it's not that easy to recompile the ActionScript. There is [Flasm](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html), but last time I checked it didn't work so well for ActionScript 3+.

Comment: @David If your Flash file does not require any Internet resources, you can try downloading it to your local drive and using the [Flash Standalone Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) to open and maximize it. Mind you, some Flash files have their size hardcoded, so it won't get any larger even if you choose full screen.

Comment: @GMMan Thanks, I will try that. And the magnifier advice, as not a bad one either.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of apps that allow you to change the resolution of your screen "automagically" before and after you run the app. If you copy it to your desktop (no installation needed) you can run it and specify the target application (then make a shortcut, that would look like the original one, and it will run seamlessly from there) and it will:

- Change the resolution to (640x480, 800x600, or whatever fits your needs).
- Run the app at that resolution.
- When you close the app, it will revert automatically to your original resolution.

One of the apps is called Qres (quickres, probably). I cannot remember the other one, but if you google Qres, the other one would appear as an alternative (and both are freeware, as far as I know).

Now, I also know, that one of those apps can integrate with the system and give you an extra tab (called Qres). So you would end up having something like this "General, Compatibility, Details, Security, QRes, ... etc".

It is what I use to work with those apps, and I rarely had any problems (you know, windows + freeware, every once in a blue moon has issues. But generally, it works!)

PS: And setting it up is quite easy - we are talking about 12-16 settings at most (including the list of resolutions).

PS2: Thanks Zero Piraeus for your corrections. As you can see English is not my native language (Unfortunatelly I only speak it as second language with French, being Spanish my native one). Still I dont get the vote down. I forgot to write PS (Post Scriptum) instead of PD (Post Data) which is use in my native language (and also in French). Amongst other small mistakes for fast typing, sorry about that. Also you removed my "@name" from my comment, while there was a couple of those in other comments. (Im just a bit puzzled, speacially for the vote down).